# /v2/locations/location_id/transactions endpoint won't save TAX

Tags: square-connect

I'm trying to push a transaction into square via the API, using the following endpoint:

```
POST https://connect.squareup.com/v2/locations/location_id/transactions

// Below the data pushed
{
    "card_nonce": "-card_nonce-",
    "idempotency_key": "-idempotency_key-",
    "reference_id": "-reference_id-",
    "amount_money": {
        "amount": 100,
        "currency": "-currency-"
    }
}
```

The problem is that, when I look at the transaction in the dashboard, the details won't display the TAX withheld for the payment. I've also created in the "taxes" tab, an appropriate tax element, which is applied to all the items.

This seems to be working fine for the payments that go through the square app, although, it doesn't work for the payments that go through the API endpoint mentioned above.

Is there any way to specify the tax in the transaction payload? if not, is there any way to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get your desired outcome, I think you want to create an [order](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#navsection-orders) first.

You should be able to create the order (with the appropriate taxes, but also itemizations and discounts as well) and then pass the `order_id` to the charge endpoint. Then your taxes should be correctly calculated, and more details reflected in Dashboard.

Comment: Thanks, although, do you see any other way to achieve this without creating the order?

Comment: I think an order would be your best bet.